# packages get not fetching .packages for English Words with proper pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, import, yaml

*for context I am currently following this exercise provided by flutter dev: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt1/#3*

I use android studio on a Windows 10 profesional.
I have seen this issue across many different areas and I am continually unable to get the English_Words package to upload. I had even uploaded the file directly the .packages and had the import work, however, the functions and classes do not validate

[image: main.dart code]
This is the import  from main.dart

[image: pubspec.yaml]
This is the pubspec.yaml, with the dependency properly spelled out

[image: .packages]
I had navigated and manually put in the `english_words` dependency. However, then the methods would not engage, even when the import worked. Furthermore, when I did ''' -flutter packages get ''', the file was removed, even with the .yaml dependency spelled out.

I have done lots of the recommended things:
-flutter doctor
-deleting the pubspec.lock and upgrading/getting packages
-shutting down the virtualization and android studio

Comment: In `pupspec.yaml` indentation is important. So put two spaces in front of `english_words:3.1.5`. Same applies for every dependency. Make sure you have indented entries appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cupertino icon and english words must have have a spacing of 2 just like flutter
ex:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  english_words:^3.1.5
```

this is a YAML file so spacing have a special meaning. just correct it as i did in example enjoy.

Comment: This worked! Thank you for making note of that, I did not see that mentioned and was an easy oversight. Thank you. I do have another problem now, as the import is no longer recognizing the methods.

Comment: I appreciate it but I did some trouble shooting myself. Thank you :)